# day and year counters in foreign digits

Tags: polyglossia, datetime2, devanagari

I'm trying to get the day and year numerals in foreign digits. So far I've been able to get the month names with a `\newcommand \date<lang>`. The language is sanskrit and the script is devanagari.

here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

% renew all representation of counters
% \renewcommand{\thesection}{\devanagarinumeral{section}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\devanagarinumeral{page}}
% \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\devanagarinumeral{enumi}}


% this one is not fine
%\renewcommand{\day}{\devanagarinumeral{day}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

% I will need to get independently day month and year
\usepackage{datetime2}

% This seems to do well for month names
\newcommand\datesanskrit{%
  \def\today{\number\day~\ifcase\month\or
    जनवरी\or फ़ेब्रवरी\or मार्च्\or एप्रील्\or मयि\or जून्\or
    जुलै\or आगस्ट्\or सेप्टम्बर्\or आक्टोबर्\or नोवेम्बर्\or दिसेम्बर्\fi 
    \space\number\year
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{दिनङ्कः}
अ आ इ ई  

\today  % here I get "18 आक्टोबर् 2023"
        % i want "१८ आक्टोबर् २०२३"
        % later i will need to place the day number,
        % the month, and the year alone independently

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\usepackage{datetime}
\newcommand\monthinsanskrit{%
  \ifcase\month\or
    जनवरी\or फ़ेब्रवरी\or मार्च्\or एप्रील्\or मयि\or जून्\or
    जुलै\or आगस्ट्\or सेप्टम्बर्\or आक्टोबर्\or नोवेम्बर्\or दिसेम्बर्\fi
  }%

\newcommand\daynameinsanskrit{%
  \computedayofweek{\day}{\month}{\year}
  \ifcase\dayofweek\or
    रविवासरः\or सोमवासरः\or मङ्गलवासरः\or बुद्धवासरः\or 
    गुरुवासरः\or शुक्रवासरः\or शनिवासरः\fi 
  }%
\newcommand\dayindevadigits{\devanagaridigits{\the\day}}
\newcommand\yearindevadigits{\devanagaridigits{\the\year}}

\newcommand\dateinsanskrit{\daynameinsanskrit, \dayindevadigits %
\monthinsanskrit~\yearindevadigits}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{दिनङ्कः}
  \dateinsanskrit

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]